# fish shell: $status variable is 0 all the time

Tags: shell, fish

I'm trying to get the status of a previous command in the fish shell prompt:

```
printf $status
```

but `$status` is equal to 0 all the time, even for commands like this:

```
$ cat some-nonexistent-file
```

The same command in the bash returns the correct status:

```
$ cat some-nonexistent-file
$ echo $?
1
```

Can anybody explain, what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry, I can't reproduce this. `printf $status` outputs 1 after running `cat non-existent-file`.
A few things to try:

1. There may be some weird function interfering. Move ~/.config/fish aside, launch a new session, and see if it still reproduces.
2. Maybe you have some unusual build. What does `echo $FISH_VERSION` show?
3. Can you post the exact script that is failing?

Comment: Thanks @ridiculous_fish - I just realized, that there are some commands, which successfully executed (with exit code 0) before the status printing, and it's a cause why status is equals to 0. I should save ``$status`` to a temporary variable at the beginning of the ``fish_prompt``.